# Split stdout between the terminal and variable

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the following function

```
import time

def foo():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"{i}. Hello world!")
        time.sleep(1)
```

I would like to save all these print calls in a variable without preventing them from reaching the terminal in real time. Essentially, `print` would output to stdout and a variable.

I have tried:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

stdout = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(stdout):
    foo()
stdout_content = stdout.getvalue()
print(stdout_content)
```

However, this blocks printing to the terminal until `foo` returns.
I would like `foo` to keep printing to the terminal in real time while an object stores the calls.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to provide your own file like object to redirect_stdout. Your object class will implement the `write` by writing both to a file and the original `sys.stdout`.

You can read about `sys.stdout` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout).
You can see the various file like classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) for solid examples.